# Reshape Long to Wide Data in R

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I am trying to reshape some user data in R.  I have a data.frame of session IDs.  Each session has a User_ID and date.  I would like to use the "User_ID" variable as my "Key" but only for the observations that have "userType" of "New Visitor".  Therefore, there will be a single row for each "New Visitor".  Then pass each subsequent Session ID as separate variable.  For instance, if a User ID has 3 Session IDs in total, there would be a total of 6 variables:

For instance, if this is the data frame for a user:

```
    date <- c('2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-02','2015-01-10')
    userID <- c('100105276','100105276','100105276','100105276')
    sessionID <- c('1452632119','1452634303','1452637067','1453600979')
    userType <- c('New Visitor','Returning Visitor','Returning Visitor','Returning Visitor')
    df <- cbind(date,userID,sessionID,userType)
```

Instead, I would like to return this:

```
    userID      sessionID1  date1      SessionID2  date2      SesionID3 date3
    100105276   1452632119  2015-01-01 1452634303  2015-01-02 100105276 2015-01-02
```

If there are any userIDs that did not have subsequent sessionIDs, a "na" value would be passed where variables are missing values.  I've read up on using tidyr or reshape2 to do this, but I haven't been able to get them to do exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: why are you dropping the last returning visitor row?

Comment: I don't want to drop it.  I was just trying to keep the example on a single row in the browser.  I want all sessions for each new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data is ordered by `userID` and `sessionID`, and each row is a unique session, you could do:

```
library(data.table)

# Transform data into data.frame
df <- data.table(df)
df[, id := sequence(.N), by = c("userID")] # session sequence number per user

# Spread columns
reshape(df, timevar = "id", idvar = "userID", direction = "wide")
#     userID     date.1 sessionID.1  userType.1     date.2 sessionID.2        userType.2     date.3 sessionID.3        userType.3     
#1 100105276 2015-01-01  1452632119 New Visitor 2015-01-02  1452634303 Returning Visitor 2015-01-02  1452637067 Returning Visitor
```

In this output `userType` is also included as a variable, but you can always drop them afterwards.

Comment: or use `reshape(..., drop = 'userType')`

Comment: After converting to `data.table`, it can be done directly from next version of data.table's dcast as follows: `dcast(df, userID ~ rowid(userID), value.var=c("sessionID", "date", "userType"), sep=".")`

Comment: @Arun nice, which version?